# OpenLayers Vector Layer not aligned with Google Oblique Imagery

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, google-maps-api

Check http://jsfiddle.net/vasile/BKvcX/6/

In the first map, the yellow line should follow the street curve, however if you pan the map up-down, you clearly see the misalignment due to what ? 
Different projection used by the oblique imagery ?

The same line, on a normal Google Maps integration (second map) is rendered "normal"

How can the misalignment in the first map be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps can optionally use perspective imagery (called also bird's eye view or 45 degree imagery) in high zoom levels. This is now set by default AFAIK and OpenLayers does not account for that.

You can switch the perspective imagery off, just add this code to your fiddle after the google layer is added to the map:

ghyb.mapObject.setTilt(0);

More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901105/how-to-disable-google-birds-eye-view-in-openlayers
http://www.fargeo.com/blog/google-maps-v3-45-degree-imagery-in-openlayers/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes